# Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp) in

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, xampp

Im using joomla 3.8.5

it worked fine but I had to reinstall xampp and now it's giving this.

---

**native.php**

```
        if (!session_start())
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to start the session');
        }

        // Mark ourselves as started
        $this->started = true;
    }
}
```

**error**

> ```
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp) in
> ```
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\libraries\joomla\session\handler\native.php
>   on line 260
>       Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

Comment: Hey guy! Did you solve this problem?
I have the same problem now...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and got this resolved.

My case:

Joomla 3 with Rockettheme template and plugins/extensions.

I tried to replicate the working site on my local wamp and I got these errors:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path:
>   c:/wamp64/tmp) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\welynx\libraries\joomla\session\handler\native.php on
>   line 260 Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the
>   session

The issue is the code cannot access the database and set up a live connection and hence cannot create a session for the current user.

After I fixed the credential and privilege on the local database/table and update them in `configuration.php`, it is no longer erroring out.

Note: if you have a customize port number in your local server, don't forget to change it in the `configuration.php`, my case is: `public $host = 'localhost:3308';`

After that, I encountered another issue that is related to RocketTheme: the PHP version!

Current wamp is running **php 7.3.1**, I received the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\wamp64\www\welynx\libraries\rokcommon\RokCommon\Registry.php on
>   line 361
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\wamp64\www\welynx\libraries\rokcommon\RokCommon\Registry.php on
>   line 363
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\wamp64\www\welynx\libraries\rokcommon\RokCommon\Registry.php on
>   line 365

The fix is to change the local wamp server to lower php edition, I set it to **php 5.6.40**, it is working as usual.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you move or reinstall Xampp to a different directory?
If so then find the following in your installation;
C:\Xampp\mysql\bin 
edit my.ini
Change the directory for the new one in Notepad++ i.e

Find 
C:
Change to 
D:
result =
D:\Xampp\mysql\bin
save my.ini and restart MySQL.
That should do it.